# Find all usages of toString() method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a huge project with a class that is widely used everywhere inside this project. This class defines `toString()` method which outputs a lot of information. I want to define another method, say, `toShortString()` and replace all of the occurrences where original `toString()` is called with this method call.

The problem is that there is a lot of code that looks like follows:

```
log.debug("Order issued: " + order);
log.debug("Loaded list of orders: " + orders);
```

where `order` is instance of this object and `orders` is a list of such objects.

Is there any way to find all such occurrences?

Any suggestions are welcome. IDE is IntelliJ Idea, if it matters.

Comment: Do you want to completely replace the `toString()` calls with `toShortString()` calls for certain objects? Are those objects of your own? Can't you simply override `toString()`? Is there any possibility of going back to the current `toString()` implementation?

Comment: This open issue on the intellij backlog seems to describe what you're looking for: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3992

Comment: You won't be able to simply replace `orders` with `orders.toShortString`.

Comment: @Gamb Yes, that's what I want to do. Yes, I own these objects. Technically, I'm trying to reduce logging by writing full state of the object only once, followed by changed fields.

Comment: @MatthewGilliard Thanks for the issue reference. Sadly, it goes way back to 2005 and probably won't be fixed anytime soon =)

Comment: what about adding  Thread.dumpStack(); to your current toString() and catch all places. Alternatively you can add an aspect based annotation and log where it called. If you lucky solaris users, then use dtrace probe to track it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply override the `toString()` method body in your `Order` class.

Technically it is not possible to find *all* calls, because even system libraries call `toString()` in many places, like all kind of collections. Also you should pay attention to your templates (whatever GUI you are using.)

So, you want to *log* the short printout, and *debug* the full (the original). Both are calling `toString()`. Then you could try to peek inside the calling stack trace to decide where is it called from. Use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to access the current stack trace.

Say, if any of the last 10 stacktrace elements is from you `Log` class, it is called for logging, then you can print the short printout. Otherwise do the full printout.

Yes, it is good practice to move the different versions of `toString()` into separate methods.

Comment: In this case I will lose information about state of this object in debugger which is not what I'd like to happen.

Comment: I think that the *state* is not lost, only you get different printout for that. I'm not familiar with Idea, but in Eclipse you can define a visualization for a certain class, probably there is a similar way in Idea as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll stick with changing the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of replacing all the occurences of `toString()` which would be error prone (you would definitely miss some) and some really difficult to replace (for example, the `System.out.println()` on a `List` of `Order` objects would always invoke `toString()` only) I suggest you modify the `toString()` itself to call `toShortString()`.

Move all the code inside `toString()` to another function called `toLongString()` and then use this function where you feel the need to have a detailed `String` representation of `Order` objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll stick with changing the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to find all **explicit** (will not find the 2 examples you showed) `toString()` calls in IDEA:

1. Inside your class mark `toString` method as `@Deprecated`.
2. `Analyze` -> `Run inspection by name` -> select `Deprecated API usage`.

It will list all usages of any deprecated APIs which of course includes the `toString` you just annotated. Don't forget to remove the annotation.

Comment: Great tip, Sam.
I think I have found a way to find **implicit** calls to toString() method of your class.

1. Remove toString() implementation from your class.
2. Run "Analyze -> Run inspection by name ->Call to default 'toString()'"

Comment: This trick did not work out for me. The `toString` method did not become crossed out, the attempt to deprecate it was simply ignored.

Answer (score 3):

In 2021 Intellij can find "implicit calls". It is an option of "Find usages settings" action (can be found by pressing double-shift).

This will help you to find occurrences like:

```java
log.debug("Order issued: " + order);
```

but unfortunately won't find collection's transformation to string:

```java
log.debug("Loaded list of orders: " + orders);
```

[image: find usages settings]